# git: get the note using the commit id of the note

Tags: git

This may sound like a silly question :P.
Supposedly, i add a note to a particular commit, say commitno

```
git notes add -m "Sample Note" $commitno
git push origin refs/master/*
```

which internally generates a commit for a note(say, commitID).
how to get the note using that commitID of the note?

Comment: I suggest you to read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273879/git-get-the-commit-id-and-the-note-of-a-commit. It has a huge explanation about notes in git. And it is just two days old

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "internally generates a commit for a note(say, commitID)", but if you mean the remote to which you push, adds a note to *its* `refs/notes/commits` pseudo-branch, you'll have to `fetch` the resulting ref to find the commit the remote added.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git branch -v
* master 6ff9387 Initial commit

$ git notes add -m "sample note" 6ff9387

$ git notes
7a902ca6d69fbd2c440ac0a714380cfd8a387262 6ff9387eeab6449cdc2948e47882725722b1145f

$ git cat-file -p 7a902ca6d69fbd2c440ac0a714380cfd8a387262
sample note
```

Comment: But here you are cat'ting the content of the file whose name is the commit ID of the commit made in another branch. I want to get the note using its own commit ID.