# Can you change old commit message title without force push?

Tags: git

Is there a way to change an old commit message without force push?

I made a typo and pushed to the master branch. Now the problem is I made a typo in the commit message. Is there a way just to edit the message without force push?

I am happy with the commit message context, I just need to update the commit message?

Is it possible?

Comment: @KenY-N not it does not, it uses force push

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+amend+without+force+push, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rebase+without+force+push

Answer (score 1):

No. Changing the commit message would change the commit identifier. So, it would technically be a different commit. So force push would be required. DON'T FORCE PUSH TO MASTER. You'll just have to live with the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the commit message results in a new commit. But [git-notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) allows to add additional remarks without changing the commit itself.

Here is a good [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269590/git-notes-details) about git notes.