# Push notes to remote git repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-notes

I recently came across some old paper documentation for a project I have archived in Git that is not reflected in the commits. Not wanting to rebase and amend all the various commits and rewrite history I decided to add the new found information via `Git Notes`. I entered the notes in my local repository.

Now I've found that I can't push these notes to the remote repository, however.

I tried the following commands: 
`git push "origin_ssh" "/refs/notes/*"`

`git push "origin_ssh" /refs/notes/commits`

`git push "origin_ssh" /refs/notes`

All of these give the error `fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in /refs/notes`

What am I doing wrong here? How do I push the notes to the remote repository?

Comment: Have you tried the commands here verbatim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268986/git-how-to-push-messages-added-by-git-notes-to-the-central-git-server , don't prefix refs with a /

Comment: Yes, the `/` was it. Thank you for the comment. Funny that thread did not come up in my search before I posted. It was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: how to push messages added by git notes to the central git server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268986/git-how-to-push-messages-added-by-git-notes-to-the-central-git-server)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Don’t add a slash before `refs/notes/*`.